# Preview in Video Sequence Editor doesn't show render layers

Tags: video-sequence-editor, render-layers

I have a scene with two objects: the cube on layer 1 and a cone on layer 2.  Under the Layers tab, I have set just the first layer to be rendered.

In the Video Sequence Editor, I added added my scene.  However, the preview window shows both layers.

[image: VSE showing both layers]

When I render, it works fine, just showing the layer 1.

[image: Just layer 1 renders as expected]

Is there any way to have the preview take into account render layers?

(Blender 2.69)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is taking the render layers into consideration, you have *OpenGL Preview* enabled so it is using that to give you a realtime viewport render which apparently takes all layers into consideration it seems, press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the view properties and untick it.

[image]